# Take values from column and put into a row

Tags: google-sheets

In google docs I am tryignt to take the values from a column in one sheet and use them as column headings in another sheet without duplicates.

Thus if sheet1 has

a

a

b

f

g

g

Sheet 2 should have it as
a b f g

In Excel I would just use VBA code, how do I do it in a google sheets?

I know the command to get it into a column, but not into a row

```
=unique(sort('Acumen Lead Tracker'!X3:X64,1,true))
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in Cell A1 of the second sheet:

```
=transpose(unique(Sheet1!A:A))
```

where Sheet1 is the sheet where the values you want to use as headers are found in col A.